# KOMA + bigfoot + lineno seem to produce vertical gaps in some cases

Tags: line-numbering, bigfoot

in a lengthy critical edition, I am using KOMA-Script, `bigfoot` and `lineno`. In certain cases, all involving footnotes, there are vertical gaps on the page containing the footnotes. This affects roughly 10-15% of the pages with footnotes (which is why I had some trouble to create a MWE or to isolate which packages might be the culprit).

I have been excluding packages one by one to track it down and it seems, that the problem is connected to these three packages. The following example will result in the last line of page 1 (line no. 42) to have an extra gap above it.
If you remove either of the `\footnoteB`, or disable line numbering, the gap will disappear (which is why I assume that it might be the combination of `lineno` and `bigfoot`).

It took me some time to figure out the following example, it is the shortest I could so far come up with; I have not yet been able to pin-point one specific reason, hence I cannot even say for certain whether this is the "right" example or just one showing the  phenomenon more or less 'by accident'.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt, twoside, paper=b5, headings=normal,
open=any, DIV=11, footlines=1, BCOR=10mm, index=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[pagewise, switch*, modulo]{lineno}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}

\begin{document}
\begin{linenumbers*}
intelligunt confuse et absque distinctione quod | patet in prima operatione. quia
ideote eodem modo intelligunt hominem animal et | rationale et album. sed logica
docet quod etiam primarii conceptus qui sunt primi | intentiones sunt ab
invicem distinguibiles intelligibiliter. quia animal | habet intelligi sub communiori
conceptu 5 quam homo. Septima ratio quia | praedicamenta sunt entia realia. et
tamen sub ordine ad aliquod accidens | rationis in logica considerantur. Unde in\footnoteB{dfg}
predicamentis ponuntur alique propri|etates predicamentorum reales ad denotandum
quod sunt encia realia | ut in predicamento substantie. Commune est omni
substantie in subiecto non esse〈.〉 | Hec sunt argumenta Montanorum Thomis10
tarum〈.〉 Et est unus de illis | qui dixit quod universale capitur dupliciter〈.〉 Uno
modo pro significato. sic universale est secunda inten|tio concretive sumpta et
universalitas abstractive sumpta. Alio modo pro de|nominato id est pro subiecto\footnoteB{test}
quod denominat. Dixit secundo quod intentio prima | est essentia naturaea vel
quidditas absolutab et secundum se apprehensa. In|tentio secunda dicitur concep15
tus comparativus secundum quod intellectus comparat naturas〈.〉 | Et dixit quod
natura universalis dupliciter concipitur per intellectum. Uno modo abso|lute. sic
omnis scientia considerat naturam universalem. Alio modo concipit natura universalis
ab | intellectu per eius speciem intelligibilem comparative. inquantum
comparatur ad in|tellectum a quo capit unitatem. et ad inferiora a quibus capit
20 multipli|citatem. sic solum in logica consideratur et substat intentionibus. hec
ille. | Et ego arguo sic. Omnis scientia habetur per demonstrationem. logica
est | scientia. ergo logica habetur per demonstrationem. Maior est nota. quia
scien|tia est habitus conclusionis per demonstationem acquisitus. sed nulla demonstra|
tio potest fieri ex secundis intentionibus. ergo logica non est de secundis
25 intenti|onibus. quia scientia per eadem acquiritur circa que est. Minor syllogismi
pro|batur. quia Omnis demonstratio fit ex necessariis veris primis. sed secunde
in|tentiones sunt ultime in ordine entium. et non sunt necessarie. quia depen- ||
[5v [A5v]] denta contingenti operatione intellectus. Secundo. Nullum ens intentio|
nale potest concurrere ad generationem entis realis. sed secunde intentiones
30 sunt | entia rationis. et logica est habitus realis. ergo non possunt concurrere ad
ac|quisitionem logice〈.〉 Tertio propter quod unumquodque tale et illud magis.
sed secunde | intentiones considerantur in logica propter primas. ergo prima magis.
Maior | 3 topicorum. 1 posteriorum
Avicenna.
patet 3 Topicorum in fine et 1 posteriorum. Minor probatur. quia
dicit Avicen|na quod logica est de secundis adiunctis primis quasi consideraret se35
cundas propter | primas. Quarto Secunde intentiones principaliter accipiuntur a
proprieta|tibus rerum. ergo proprietates rerum principaliter considerantur in logica.
sed pro|prietates rerum sunt reales. ergo res sunt cause intentionum. probatur
| prima pars maioris per S anctum Tho mam de universalibus trac. 2 opus 2⒍ B eatus Tho mas
Quinto | Quero ex te quare intellectus tuus non potest attribuere homini hanc |
40 intentionem secundam genus. Si dicis quia proprietas hominis non est talis quod
| multiplicetur per species. ergo convenit homini ex natura rei illa intentio species
| et non genus. Ex illo arguo sic Quicumque considerat aliquod accidens | propter
principium. ille magis considerat principium et radicem super qua fun|datur.
et ex qua sequitur hoc accidens. Sed logicus considerat secundas intentiones |
propter unam radicem vel fecunditatem sive sit .a. sive .b. ergo principaliter con- 5
si|derat hoc principium vel formale primarum intentionum. Confirmatur per |
B eatus Tho mas S anctum Tho mam de natura generis ca. ⒌ ubi dicit quod universale capitur
dupliciter Uno | modo pro ipsa natura cui intellectus propter aliquid in ea inventum
inten|tionem attribuit. et sic universalia que rerum naturas significant
7 metaphi sice predicantur in quid. | animal namque est substantia illius de quo predicatur et 10
B eatus Tho mas similiter homo. Idem patet 7 metaphisi|ce. lec. ⒔ In oppositum tamen et pro
veritate est D octoris S ancti 4 meta|phisice. lec. 4 in opusculo de universalibus
trac. 2 Et quia h oc magis Thoma|stris aliquibus reluctabor. ideo eum inferius
in testem vocabo. Et | arguo sic. Si logica est de primis intentionibus. vel natura
considera|ta in logica consideratur sub eadem ratione sicut in aliis scientiis. vel 15
non | Si primum. sequitur quod logica ratione obiecti erit scientia realis quod est
4 metaphi sice contra Aristotelem 4 metaphisice. et contra S anctum Tho mam undiquaque. Si
secundum Tunc | quero vel illa natura realis universalis consideratur sub eadem
unitate. vel sub alia | unitate Si dicis sub alia unitate Quero Utrum sit unitas
rationis vel | unitas rei. Utrum sit absoluta vel respectiva. Non potes dicere quod
\end{linenumbers*}
\end{document}
```

Any help is highly appreciated; if there is another way to provide a line numbering that will work around this problem, I'll be glad to give it a try.

TIA,
Dario

--

As requested, here is a snapshot of the last few lines including the footnote:
[image: The gap is between lines 41 and 42]

---

Edit 2015-06-05:

I found another, shorter example which also shows that KOMA is not involved but rather it's really only `lineno` and `bigfoot`. Plus, you'll really see it this time. It's not only a small additional gap this time.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}
%\usepackage[pagewise, switch*, modulo]{lineno}

\begin{document}
\begin{linenumbers*} 
{[*1r:]}  
\stepcounter{footnoteA}\footnotemarkA[\value{footnoteA}]Der fridliche anstand: 
    zu franckfurt aufgericht im Aprilen
    Anno. M.D.XXXIX\footnotemarkA[\value{footnoteA}]\footnotetextA{Fehlt \textsc{Ganzer}, Akten 1\nolinebreak /2, S. 1072, Z. 7.}
\par Von gottes gnaden \nolinebreak / Wir, Ludwig, Pfaltzgraffe 
    bey Rhein \nolinebreak / Hertzog inn Bayern{bayern kurfuerstentum} \nolinebreak / Unnd wir vonn 
    den selbigen gnaden Gottes \nolinebreak / Joachim, Margraff\footnoteA{\textsc{Ganzer}, Akten 1\nolinebreak /2, S. 1072, Z. 8: \textit{aufgrund fehlerhafter Transkription} Burggrave \textit{statt} Marggrave.} zu 
    Brandenburg \nolinebreak / zu Stetin \nolinebreak / Pomern, der Cassuben \nolinebreak / 
    Wenden \nolinebreak / unnd in Schlesien zu Crossen Hertzog \nolinebreak / 
    Burggra{v}e zu Nürenberg unn Fürst zu Rüegen \nolinebreak / des 
    hailigen Römischen Reichs \nolinebreak / Ertzthruchses und Ertz Camerer, beide Curfürsten \nolinebreak / Bekennen unnd thun kundt 
    offentlich mit disem brieff \nolinebreak /, Als aus dem Nüerenbergischen Fridstandt, der hiebe{v}or der mindern zal Im 
    XXXII. jar auffgerichtet worden \nolinebreak /\footnoteB{Vgl. den Nürnberger Anstand vom 24.7.1532, oben S.\#.} ain miß{v}erstandt\footnoteB{Dissens, Streit.} 
    fürgefallen \nolinebreak / Und der Aller durchleuchtigest \nolinebreak / Großmächtigest Fürst und herr \nolinebreak / Herr Carel \nolinebreak / Römischer 
    Käyser, zu allen zeiten \nolinebreak / mehrer des Reichs, inn Germanien, zu Hispanien \nolinebreak / baider Sicilien \nolinebreak / Jerusalem, Hungeren., Dalmatien \nolinebreak / Croatien \nolinebreak / König \nolinebreak / Ertzhertzog \stepcounter{footnoteA}\footnotemarkA[\value{footnoteA}]zu
    Osterreich\footnotemarkA[\value{footnoteA}]\footnotetextA{Fehlt aufgrund fehlerhafter Transkription \textsc{Ganzer}, Akten 1\nolinebreak /2, S. 1072, Z. 16.}
    \nolinebreak / herzog\footnoteA{Ergänzt nach   Frankfurt a. M., Institut für Stadtgeschichte, Reichssachen Urkunden Nr. 449, fol. 3r. Fehlt aufgrund fehlerhafter Transkription \textsc{Ganzer}, Akten 1\nolinebreak /2, S. 1072, Z. 16.}
    zu Burgundi \nolinebreak / Brabandt \nolinebreak / Gra{v}e zu Habspurg \nolinebreak / Flandern und Tirol \nolinebreak / etc., Unser allergnedigister herr \nolinebreak / 
    aus besondern Käyserlichen, vätterlichen, milten gnaden unn 
    guotem\footnoteA{\textsc{Ganzer}, Akten 1\nolinebreak /2, S. 1072, Z. 18: \textit{aufgrund fehlerhafter Transkription} guten \textit{statt} gutem.} 
\end{linenumbers*} 

\end{document}
```

Without `lineno`, it'll work just fine. If you uncomment it, well, see for yourself.

I have recently added a question for any substitute for `lineno` - and I'd like to extend that to any substitute for `bigfoot`.
As I need the first apparatus to be typeset as one paragraph (with footnotemarks in the style of either »a« or »a-a«, per page) and the other as one paragraph per footnote (count 1... per chapter), the alternative solution would be able to provide a possibility for that formatting.

Thanks again to all helpers and for all your suggestions!

Comment: I have just tried pdflatex and I'm still left with a gap, albeit less pronounced.

Comment: You could try `\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}` instead of bigfoot.

Comment: Ulrike, unfortunately, manyfoot is not an option in my case. In order to provide a MWE, I left out the complete definition for my footnotes; I do have 2 types of footnotes set in paragraph mode and one as one paragraph per footnote. This does not seem to be possible with manyfoot.

Comment: Have you looked at the packages which are designed specifically for typesetting critical editions? I do not know a great deal about them so I cannot say off-hand if they have the precise features you need but it would at least be worth a look as they are designed to provide a fairly integrated/unified solution to typesetting this kind of text. See [this CTAN topic](http://ctan.org/topic/crit-ed). **reledmac** / **reledpar** are fairly new, designed to be replacements for their predecessors. (First there was **edmac** then **ledmac** then **eledmac** and now **reledmac**.)