# How to number lines (per page and on the inner margin) without lineno?

Tags: line-numbering

I have been experimenting a lot lately to find a cure to [the question I asked in December](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218442/koma-bigfoot-lineno-seem-to-produce-vertical-gaps-in-some-cases) but as of yet I have been unsuccessful. Now, while this is entirely due to the fact that I do not have enough time to completely dive into the depths of TeX, I still need a solution.

So, what I need is a way to output a line numbering, per-page, modulo 5 on the inner margin that does not use lineno, or a solution to my old problem.

Any help is highly appreciated.

TIA,
Dario

Comment: Are we to understand you want "actual" line numbering, as opposed to marginal numbering at regular `\baselineskip` intervals?  In the former, empty space is not numbered, in the latter, it is.

Comment: »Actual« line numbering, disregarding empty space, is what I am looking for. Preferably including lines in tables (but that is not too important if I have something that does the trick for the rest).
Thanks, D.

Comment: To add to this: I have already tried using eledmac for line numbering but that wreaks even more havoc than does the combination of lineno and bigfoot.
I thought about switching to eledmac for both line numbering and footnotes but from what I see, it is not possible to have footnotes displayed the way I need them.
Anyway, I'm back to square one and reach out for your combined expertise.